# How to find a bijective map from interval to R and from interval to interval

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm trying to help my girlfriend with her homework, but I'm really bad at finding bijective functions between 2 intervals, so does anyone can give us some tips to find the bijective maps?

a) from $\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 7},0\right)$ to $\left(-\sqrt3, \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right)$

b) from $\left(-\sqrt 5,0\right)$ to $\mathbb{R}$

If you find the bijective map would be awesome, but we also want some tips to help us to find the bijective maps by our selves. Thanks a lot. Greetings from Mexico City.

Comment: Write system of linear equations for first.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709910/for-a-b-in-mathbb-r-with-ab-find-an-explicit-function-which-is-a-bijectio)

Answer (score 3):

If you have two finite intervals, a simple way is to write a linear function. $$f(x)=ax+b$$
So for the first one, you can write $$f\left(\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt 7}\right)=-\sqrt 3$$
and $$f(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$$
From these two identities you can find out $a$ and $b$.

If you have the first interval finite and the second $\mathbb R$ you can use a transformation of the type $\tan x$. You might need to scale $x$ first, sso at the top of the interval $x=\pi/2$, and at bottom is $-\pi/2$. If the first interval is $\mathbb R$ and the second is a finite interval, you can probably use arctangent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tip to find another solution for (b).

If you can solve (a), you should be able to map $(-\sqrt5,0)$ to $(-1,1)$.

Then compose that map with $g(x):(-1,1)\to\mathbb R$ defined by $g(x)=\dfrac x{1-x^2}$.